# Multiple Autocomplete Widget

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anybody suggest widgets that deal with multiple autocomplete selections, rather than just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **Chosen** - http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Specifically, look at the *multiple sections* demo they have on their page under the *Selected and Disabled Support* section.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [JQuery Auto Complete widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple). You could use it out of the box, or build on the same principle.